# C# MVC Create route for all methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

**Old**

I have created a new route for my application, which is as follows

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{custom}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { custom = new RouteValidation() }
        );
```

While it works, it only works for Home/Index. When I want to go to Home/Login it just reloads the page. This worked before the new route.

My question, do I need to create a new route for every method or is there a better way to do this?

**Update**

What I would like to get is an url like this `localhost/{custom}/{controller}/{action}/{id}` where 'custom' is a unique id to get information from a company.

```
1234 = company 'A' -> localhost/1234/Home/Index
0987 = company 'B' -> localhost/0987/Home/Index
```

Here is my complete routing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Route1",
        url: "{custom}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { custom = new CustomerServiceModule.Helpers.RouteValidation() }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

}

Here is my RouteValidation, this check whether the `{custom}` is a valid id or not, this works.

```
public class RouteValidation : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {                        
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.IncomingRequest)
        {
            //returns true if the 'custom' is valid else false
            return CheckPublicationUniqueID(values["custom"].ToString());
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here are some routes of the application

```
Index/Home
Index/Login
Subscription/Index
Subscription/Edit/{id}
Subscription/Details/{id}
Invoice/Index
History/Index
```

The problem that I have is that if I navigate to lets say 'Subscription/Index' the 'custom' is gone from the url and if I remove the default route it does not go to any of the above named urls.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Did you replace the default route with this one or does the default "Default" route still exist as well? What URLs are you actually routing? Is it literally `/Home/Index` and `/Home/Login`? And, if so, what role does `{custom}` play? It might help if you posted your entire `RouteConfig.cs`.

Comment: Chris is right. Please post your entire route configuration (including the RotueValidation() constriant) and indicate what is *broken* with your configuration. If you go to `/Home/Index` with this configuration, you are indicating that you want to go to a controller named `Index` and an action named `Index` based on your `url` parameter (which doesn't seem correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution for my problem.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CompanyRouteWithoutParameters",
            "{company}/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
            new { company = new RouteValidation() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "CompanyRouteWithParameters",
            "{company}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure how you consider this to be a "solution". The first route can *never* match because there is no `{publisher}` segment in the URL. You might as well just remove it altogether. The second route will not work unless you specify the company, otherwise you will get a 404 - difficult to tell if that is intended or not, but since you put URLs without a company in your question, I am guessing no.

Answer (score 0):

The default route is just for when you application fires up you can use:

```
@Html.RouteLink("LINKTEXT", new { action = "ACTION", controller = "CONTROLLER", area = "AREA IF THERE IS ONE" })
```

This would be in your navigation.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

If you wanted to you could have them all in the RouteConfig.cs but its just messy and not needed. If your calling methods that are not to do with navigation you need a totally different approach, i.e. ajax for example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/Method",
    success: function (data) {
          // do bits
    }
});
```

This is useful for that http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp